# QuickBooks Desktop Build Assembly

Tags: quickbooks

I have been using PHP SDK for integrating QuickBooks Desktop with applications.

However, I got stuck trying to Build Assembly.

It does have a file named BuildAssemblyAddRq.php which would make one think that it does support building assemblies but it did not work.

I don't have to use PHP. I am open to using .NET too. However, I see no mention of BuildAssemblyAdd on https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/Common/newOSR/index.html which makes me think if it's even possible.

If it's not possible, then why is it talking about it in https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/doc/PDF/QBSDK_ProGuide.pdf.

To sum it up, does the PHP SDK support BuildAssemblyAdd? 
If not, does QuickBooks SDK itself support BuildAssemblyAdd?
If not, what are my options?

Edit: Yes, it does support BuildAssemblyAdd but only on higher QuickBooks versions. I was running it on older versions and that is why it failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to actually create an `Assembly Item`, you want `ItemInventoryAssemblyAdd`.

If you're trying to actually "build" stuff (e.g. assembly stuff and put it into inventory) then you want `BuildAssemblyAdd`.

> does the PHP SDK support BuildAssemblyAdd?

Probably.

What SDK are you referring to here? Link?

> If not, does QuickBooks SDK itself support BuildAssemblyAdd?

Yes.

`BuildAssemblyAdd` is documented as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="13.0"?>
<QBXML>
    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
        <BuildAssemblyAddRq>
            <BuildAssemblyAdd defMacro="MACROTYPE">
                <!-- required -->
                <ItemInventoryAssemblyRef>
                    <!-- required -->
                    <ListID>IDTYPE</ListID>
                    <!-- optional -->
                    <FullName>STRTYPE</FullName>
                    <!-- optional -->
                </ItemInventoryAssemblyRef>
                <InventorySiteRef>
                    <!-- optional -->
                    <ListID>IDTYPE</ListID>
                    <!-- optional -->
                    <FullName>STRTYPE</FullName>
                    <!-- optional -->
                </InventorySiteRef>
                <InventorySiteLocationRef>
                    <!-- optional -->
                    <ListID>IDTYPE</ListID>
                    <!-- optional -->
                    <FullName>STRTYPE</FullName>
                    <!-- optional -->
                </InventorySiteLocationRef>
                <!-- BEGIN OR -->
                <SerialNumber>STRTYPE</SerialNumber>
                <!-- optional -->
                <!-- OR -->
                <LotNumber>STRTYPE</LotNumber>
                <!-- optional -->
                <!-- END OR -->
                <TxnDate>DATETYPE</TxnDate>
                <!-- optional -->
                <RefNumber>STRTYPE</RefNumber>
                <!-- optional -->
                <Memo>STRTYPE</Memo>
                <!-- optional -->
                <QuantityToBuild>QUANTYPE</QuantityToBuild>
                <!-- required -->
                <MarkPendingIfRequired>BOOLTYPE</MarkPendingIfRequired>
                <!-- optional -->
                <ExternalGUID>GUIDTYPE</ExternalGUID>
                <!-- optional -->
            </BuildAssemblyAdd>
            <IncludeRetElement>STRTYPE</IncludeRetElement>
            <!-- optional, may repeat -->
        </BuildAssemblyAddRq>
    </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

`ItemInventoryAssemblyAdd` is documented in the OSR as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="13.0"?>
<QBXML>
    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
        <ItemInventoryAssemblyAddRq>
            <ItemInventoryAssemblyAdd>
                <!-- required -->
                <Name>STRTYPE</Name>
                <!-- required -->
                <BarCode>
                    <!-- optional -->
                    <BarCodeValue>STRTYPE</BarCodeValue>
                    <!-- optional -->
                    <AssignEvenIfUsed>BOOLTYPE</AssignEvenIfUsed>
                    <!-- optional -->
                    <AllowOverride>BOOLTYPE</AllowOverride>
                    <!-- optional -->
                </BarCode>
                <IsActive>BOOLTYPE</IsActive>
                <!-- optional -->
                <ClassRef>
                    <!-- optional -->
                    <ListID>IDTYPE</ListID>
                    <!-- optional -->
                    <FullName>STRTYPE</FullName>
                    <!-- optional -->
                </ClassRef>
                <ParentRef>
                    <!-- optional -->
                    <ListID>IDTYPE</ListID>
                    <!-- optional -->
                    <FullName>STRTYPE</FullName>
                    <!-- optional -->
                </ParentRef>
                <ManufacturerPartNumber>STRTYPE</ManufacturerPartNumber>
                <!-- optional -->
                <UnitOfMeasureSetRef>
                    <!-- optional -->
                    <ListID>IDTYPE</ListID>
                    <!-- optional -->
                    <FullName>STRTYPE</FullName>
                    <!-- optional -->
                </UnitOfMeasureSetRef>
                <SalesTaxCodeRef>
                    <!-- optional -->
                    <ListID>IDTYPE</ListID>
                    <!-- optional -->
                    <FullName>STRTYPE</FullName>
                    <!-- optional -->
                </SalesTaxCodeRef>
                <SalesDesc>STRTYPE</SalesDesc>
                <!-- optional -->
                <SalesPrice>PRICETYPE</SalesPrice>
                <!-- optional -->
                <IncomeAccountRef>
                    <!-- optional -->
                    <ListID>IDTYPE</ListID>
                    <!-- optional -->
                    <FullName>STRTYPE</FullName>
                    <!-- optional -->
                </IncomeAccountRef>
                <PurchaseDesc>STRTYPE</PurchaseDesc>
                <!-- optional -->
                <PurchaseCost>PRICETYPE</PurchaseCost>
                <!-- optional -->
                <COGSAccountRef>
                    <!-- optional -->
                    <ListID>IDTYPE</ListID>
                    <!-- optional -->
                    <FullName>STRTYPE</FullName>
                    <!-- optional -->
                </COGSAccountRef>
                <PrefVendorRef>
                    <!-- optional -->
                    <ListID>IDTYPE</ListID>
                    <!-- optional -->
                    <FullName>STRTYPE</FullName>
                    <!-- optional -->
                </PrefVendorRef>
                <AssetAccountRef>
                    <!-- optional -->
                    <ListID>IDTYPE</ListID>
                    <!-- optional -->
                    <FullName>STRTYPE</FullName>
                    <!-- optional -->
                </AssetAccountRef>
                <BuildPoint>QUANTYPE</BuildPoint>
                <!-- optional -->
                <Max>QUANTYPE</Max>
                <!-- optional -->
                <QuantityOnHand>QUANTYPE</QuantityOnHand>
                <!-- optional -->
                <TotalValue>AMTTYPE</TotalValue>
                <!-- optional -->
                <InventoryDate>DATETYPE</InventoryDate>
                <!-- optional -->
                <ExternalGUID>GUIDTYPE</ExternalGUID>
                <!-- optional -->
                <ItemInventoryAssemblyLine>
                    <!-- optional, may repeat -->
                    <ItemInventoryRef>
                        <!-- required -->
                        <ListID>IDTYPE</ListID>
                        <!-- optional -->
                        <FullName>STRTYPE</FullName>
                        <!-- optional -->
                    </ItemInventoryRef>
                    <Quantity>QUANTYPE</Quantity>
                    <!-- optional -->
                </ItemInventoryAssemblyLine>
            </ItemInventoryAssemblyAdd>
            <IncludeRetElement>STRTYPE</IncludeRetElement>
            <!-- optional, may repeat -->
        </ItemInventoryAssemblyAddRq>
    </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

Comment: I was referring to your PHP SDK! By the way, the problem with ItemInventoryAssemblyAdd is QuantityOnHand parameter is only available in ItemInventoryAssemblyAdd and NOT ItemInventoryAssemblyMod. But I am not trying to create a new Inventory Assembly Item. The assembly item already has been created. I only need to tweak a specific part of an existing assembly item -"QuantityOnHand" - which is essentially what "build" command of QuickBooks does. It increases the QuantityOnHand and subtracts quantityonhand of components. Can you please answer my dilemma?